# graphite webapp doesn't show data from all carbon cache process

Tags: graphite

i am running 4 carbon cache instance behind 1 carbon relay instance. Below is my  carbon.conf.

```
[cache:1]
        LINE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2103
        PICKLE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2104
        CACHE_QUERY_PORT = 7102
        STORAGE_DIR = /graphite_data/01
        LOCAL_DATA_DIR = /graphite_data/01

        [cache:2]
        LINE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2203
        PICKLE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2204
        CACHE_QUERY_PORT = 7202
        STORAGE_DIR = /graphite_data/02
        LOCAL_DATA_DIR = /graphite_data/02

        [cache:3]
        LINE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2303
        PICKLE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2304
        CACHE_QUERY_PORT = 7302
        STORAGE_DIR = /graphite_data/03
        LOCAL_DATA_DIR = /graphite_data/03

        [cache:4]
        LINE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2403
        PICKLE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2404
        CACHE_QUERY_PORT = 7402
        STORAGE_DIR = /graphite_data/04
        LOCAL_DATA_DIR = /graphite_data/04
```

I have configured my carbon relay with below configutaion

```
    LINE_RECEIVER_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
    LINE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2003
    PICKLE_RECEIVER_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
    PICKLE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2004
    RELAY_METHOD = consistent-hashing

 .
    REPLICATION_FACTOR = 1
    DESTINATIONS=127.0.0.1:2104:1,127.0.0.1:2204:2,127.0.0.1:2304:3,127.0.0.1:2404:4
```

I have configured my graphite webapp with the below configuration to get the data from all carbon cache process

```
    STANDARD_DIRS = ['/graphite_data/01',
                     '/graphite_data/02',
                     '/graphite_data/03',
                     '/graphite_data/04']
    # You *should* use 127.0.0.1 here in most cases
    CARBONLINK_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1:7102:1", "127.0.0.1:7202:2", "127.0.0.1:7302:3","127.0.0.1:7402:4"]
```

After configuration , i started pushing data with example-client.py to my carbon relay process. I could see that relay is pushing data to carbon-cache process.

```
**[root@poc-graphite graphite]# ls /graphite_data/02/system/loadavg_5min.wsp 
/graphite_data/02/system/loadavg_5min.wsp
[root@poc-graphite graphite]# ls /graphite_data/03/system/loadavg_1min.wsp 
/graphite_data/03/system/loadavg_1min.wsp
[root@poc-graphite graphite]# ls /graphite_data/04/system/loadavg_15min.wsp 
/graphite_data/04/system/loadavg_15min.wsp**
```

But I am not able to see this metrics in my webapp. is there something wrong with configuration.[image]

Comment: hi, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the path of the twisted plugin with blow commands:

```
$python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

If in the results exist the path **"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"**, just remove it:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twiste*
```

and then

```
sudo service carbon-cache stop      ## wait a few seconds here
sudo service carbon-cache start
```